# Issue With Adding a UI Element at Runtime

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard

I have this situation :

[image]

This pink view in the scrollview and I want is:

when I tap on 'add' button, I want that to create another pink view object (this is no problem) and set it below the first pink view object setting auto layout for it(vertical space between it and previous pink view object, trailing space .....) but I don't be able to do this part.

Can you help me?

Comment: Why you are not using tableview for this?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: as @iOS_devloper mentioned, assuming for those cases using a table view -or maybe a collection view, depends on what your case is- is much better

Comment: I thought about table view or collection view but for several reasons(that I can't explain them here) I have to do this in those way

Comment: I'm guessing you want to do it in code so can you please update the tags to one language only. is it swift or objective-c

Comment: only swift. I updated it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you have problem adding view to scrollview. Here is example for adding button into scrollview at runtime. You can use same code for adding your pink view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate
{

    var pickerviewObj : UIPickerView!=UIPickerView()
    var scrlview: UIScrollView = UIScrollView();
    var cotentView : UIView = UIView();
    var arrdata :NSMutableArray=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
    var dctButtons : NSMutableDictionary!=NSMutableDictionary()
    var    ContentViewconstraintheight : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var xPos,ypos: NSInteger!
    var SelctedTag : NSInteger!

    var width: Double!

    // var colors = ["Red","Yellow","Green","Blue"]

    func getCalculatedHeightForScren(height : CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        return (height *  self.view.frame.size.height/568  );

    }
    func disableAutoResizingMasks() {
        self.pickerviewObj.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.scrlview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.cotentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    }
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let  pickerHeight  = getCalculatedHeightForScren(height: 50)
        self.pickerviewObj = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height-pickerHeight, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: pickerHeight) )
        self.view.addSubview(self.pickerviewObj);
        pickerviewObj.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;
        pickerviewObj.showsSelectionIndicator = true;
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default;

        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        self.view.addSubview(self.scrlview)
        self.scrlview.addSubview(self.cotentView);
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.DonePicker))

        toolBar.setItems([  spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toolBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height-pickerHeight-44, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 44);
        self.view.addSubview(toolBar);
        pickerviewObj.dataSource = self;
        pickerviewObj.delegate = self;


        //add constraints to PickerView

        let constraintCenterX =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerviewObj, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant:0);
        let constraintBottom =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerviewObj, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant:0);

        let constraintWidth =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerviewObj, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1, constant:0);

        let constraintHeight =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerviewObj, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, multiplier: (200/568), constant:0);




        //add constraints to ScrollView


        let scrollconstraintCenterX =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrlview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant:0);
        let scrollconstraintBottom =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrlview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: toolBar     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant:0);

        let scrollconstraintWidth =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrlview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1, constant:0);

        let scrollconstraintTop =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrlview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier:1, constant:0);

        //add constraints to ScrollView's contentView

        let ContentViewconstrainttop =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.cotentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.scrlview     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.topMargin, multiplier: 1, constant:0);
        let ContentViewconstraintBottom =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.cotentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.scrlview     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant:0);

        let ContentViewconstraintleft =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.cotentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.scrlview     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant:0);

        let ContentViewconstraintright =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.cotentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.scrlview     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: (200/568), constant:0);


        let ContentViewconstraintWidth =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.cotentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.scrlview     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1, constant:0);
        self.ContentViewconstraintheight =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.cotentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant:100);



        //add constraints to toolBar

        let toolconstraintCenterX =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant:0);

        let toolconstraintBottom =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.pickerviewObj     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant:0);

        let toolconstraintWidth =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1, constant:0);

        //activare all constraints


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([constraintWidth,constraintHeight,constraintCenterX,constraintBottom,toolconstraintWidth,toolconstraintBottom,toolconstraintCenterX,scrollconstraintTop,scrollconstraintWidth,scrollconstraintCenterX,scrollconstraintBottom,ContentViewconstrainttop,ContentViewconstraintBottom,ContentViewconstraintleft,ContentViewconstraintright,ContentViewconstraintWidth,self.ContentViewconstraintheight]);
        self.view.layoutSubviews()
        self.disableAutoResizingMasks();
        toolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func getSorted(s1 : Any , s2 : Any) -> Bool{
        let str1 : String = s1 as! String
        let str2 : String = s2 as! String
        return Int(str1)! <  Int(str2)!;

    }
    //custom Logics to Update UI
    func addConstarintsToButton(btn : UIButton , yPos : CGFloat)
    {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(btn.constraints);
        btn.removeConstraints(btn.constraints);

        let width = ((self.view.frame.size.width-20)/2) - 30;
        let height = self.getCalculatedHeightForScren(height: 40);

        let constraintCenterX =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.scrlview     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant:0);

        let constrainttop =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.cotentView     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant:yPos);

        let constraintWidth =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: width);

        let constraintHeight =    NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil     , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: height, constant:height);

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([constraintCenterX, constrainttop,constraintWidth,constraintHeight])


        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    func updateUIElements(tag : Int)
    {

        let arrKeys : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: dctButtons.allKeys, copyItems: true)
        let SortedKeys =     arrKeys.sorted(by: getSorted)

        var xPos :CGFloat = 10.0;
        var yPos :CGFloat = 50.0;
        let width = ((self.view.frame.size.width-20)/2) - 30;
        let height = self.getCalculatedHeightForScren(height: 40);

        xPos = (self.view.frame.size.width - width)/2;

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:  {

            if(tag > 0)
            {
                let vw = self.cotentView.viewWithTag(tag)
                vw?.removeFromSuperview()

                let vw1 = self.cotentView.viewWithTag(tag + 100)
                vw1?.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            for key in SortedKeys {

                let  btn1 = self.dctButtons.object(forKey: key) as! UIButton
                btn1.frame = CGRect( x:xPos, y:yPos,width:width,height:height);
                if let testBtn = self.cotentView.viewWithTag(btn1.tag+100) as? UIButton
                {

                    let btnCross =  testBtn  ;
                    btnCross.frame = CGRect(x: xPos + btn1.frame.size.width + 5, y: yPos, width: 20, height: height);
                }


                self.ContentViewconstraintheight.constant = btn1.frame.size.height + 100;
                if let vw = self.cotentView.viewWithTag(btn1.tag) as? UIButton
                {
                    vw.removeFromSuperview();
                    self.cotentView.addSubview(btn1);
                    self.addConstarintsToButton(btn: btn1, yPos: yPos);

                }
                else{
                    self.cotentView.addSubview(btn1);
                    self.addConstarintsToButton(btn: btn1, yPos: yPos);

                }
                yPos  += height + 10

            }
            self.view.layoutSubviews()
            self.ContentViewconstraintheight.constant = yPos ;

        })


    }


    // Control event Methods....


    func btnClick(sender: UIButton!)
    {
        SelctedTag=sender.tag;
        print(SelctedTag)
        if sender.isSelected
        {
            return;
        }
        sender.isSelected = true;

        let ButtonClose = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: sender.frame.origin.x + sender.frame.size.width + 5, y: sender.frame.origin.y, width: 20, height: sender.frame.size.height) )
        ButtonClose.tag = sender.tag + 100;
        ButtonClose.setTitle("X", for: UIControlState.normal)
        ButtonClose.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        ButtonClose.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: UIControlState.normal);
        ButtonClose.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        ButtonClose.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.btnClose(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside);
        self.cotentView.addSubview(ButtonClose);

        let strVal = String(sender.tag)

        self.arrdata.remove(strVal)
        self.pickerviewObj.reloadComponent(0);

    }
    func DonePicker()
    {
        let selectedIndex = self.pickerviewObj.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
        if (arrdata.count == 0 ||  selectedIndex < 0  || selectedIndex > arrdata.count )
        {
            return;
        }
        let x : String = arrdata[selectedIndex] as! String
        let tag = Int(x)!
        if let vw = self.cotentView.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIButton
        {
            return;
        }

        let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system);
        btn.isSelected = false;
        btn.tag =  tag
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.black;
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ViewController.btnClick(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        btn.setTitle("Field " + String(x), for: UIControlState.normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        btn.center = self.pickerviewObj.center;
        dctButtons.setObject(btn, forKey: String(x) as NSCopying)
        self.pickerviewObj.reloadComponent(0);
        self.updateUIElements(tag: 0);
    }

    func btnClose(sender: UIButton!)
    {
        print((SelctedTag))
        let key = String(sender.tag - 100);
        dctButtons.removeObject(forKey: key);
        arrdata.add( key)
        let tmpArray = arrdata.sorted(by: getSorted)
        arrdata.removeAllObjects();
        arrdata.addObjects(from: tmpArray)
        self.pickerviewObj.reloadComponent(0);
        self.updateUIElements(tag: sender.tag - 100);

    }

    // Picker view Methods....

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return arrdata.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
    {
        let x : String = arrdata[row] as! String
        return  "Field " + x
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        //        let x : Int = arrdata[row] as! Int
        //        arrButton.add(x)
        //        print(arrButton)

        //       self .numberOfButton(number: arrdata[row] as! Int)
        //       arrdata.removeObject(at: row)
        //       pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }
```

}